# Vue. Как передать данные из одного компонента в другой?

Tags: javascript, vue3

Есть компонент отображающий список товаров (получаю с сервера по API) и есть компонент который должен отображать один товар.
Как по клику на ссылку передать данные в компонент отображающий один товар во Vue3?